# Select a segment using title

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I can select a segment's index, if I know its index using something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tipSegment: UISegmentedControl!
.
.
.
tipSegment.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
```

How can I select a segment if I only have its title?

One crude way is to have all titles in an array, find index of title I have from the array, and then use that index but I wanted to see if I can avoid creating such an array and just enable the label using its title.

Problem is that I am loading title from NSUserDefaults where I don't save the index and just want to set the segment of SegmentControl which has that title on loading the View for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saving the title in NSUserDefaults, save the index!

Otherwise, you'll have to call `titleForSegmentAtIndex:` repeatedly to get all the segment titles and compare to each one. That is certainly do-able, but it's going to get old very fast. Besides, titles are localizable, but index numbers are invariant.

Comment: haha...not sure why that didn't come to my mind. Thanks @matt